# Error Message in Laravel

Tags: redirect, laravel

Im using redirect::back()->withErrors($exception) but not able to display error message on my page.
Here is my controller

```
try{

    }
    catch(ParseException $pex){
        $error=var_dump($pex->getMessage());
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErros(array('msg'=>$error));
    }
```

and here is my view

```
{ Form::open(array('action' =>'UsersController@register','class' => 'form-horizontal','id'=> 'registrationForm' ,'name' => 'registrationForm','method' => 'POST')) }}
            <div class="body bg-gray">
                <!--Kullanicinin girmesi gereken bilgiler-->
                @if($errors->any())
                    <div class="form-group has-error">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                 <h4>Error:{{$erros->first('code')}}</h4><br/>
                                 <label>{{$errors->first('msg')}}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endif
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: `withErros` dont you mean `withErrors`? That is within your catch segment.

Comment: Exactly, it should be withErrors. By the way, it was a stupid syntax mistake it is fixed.